# Is there any flaw in binary tree destructor algorithm

Tags: c++, c++17, binary-tree

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#define vi vector<int>

using namespace std;


class node{
    public:
        int data;
        node *left;
        node *right;

        node(){
            data = 0;
            left = right = nullptr;
        }

        node(int data){
            this->data = data;
            left = right = nullptr;
        }
};

class BT{
public:
    node *root{nullptr};
public:
    BT(){
        root = nullptr;
    }
    BT(const vi& v){
        // create a pair with initial state 0 and having root node in it
        stack<pair<node*,int> > st;
        root = new node(v[0]);
        pair<node*,int> p(root,0);
        st.push(p);

        int idx = 1;

        while(idx < v.size())
        {
            pair<node *,int> p = st.top();
            int state = p.second;
            int val = v[idx];

            if(state == 2)
            {
                st.pop();
                continue;
            }

            if(val == -1)
            {
                // will think for here
                // p.second++;
                st.top().second++;
                idx++;
                continue;
            }

            // Now the value is not -1 and state is not 2

            node *newNode = new node(val);

            if(state == 0)
            {
                st.top().first->left = newNode;
                // p.first->left = newNode;
            }else{
                st.top().first->right = newNode;
                // p.first->right = newNode;
            }

            st.top().second++;
            st.push(pair<node*,int>(newNode,0));
            idx++;

        }
    }

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os,BT& b){
        b.printHelper(b.root,os);
        return os;
    }

    void printHelper(node *root,ostream& os){
        if(root == nullptr)
            return;

        if(root->left != nullptr)
            os << (root->left)->data;
        os <<  " <- " << root->data << " -> ";

        if(root->right != nullptr)
            os << root->right->data;
        os << endl;
        printHelper(root->left,os);
        printHelper(root->right,os);
    }


    void levelOrderLineWise(){
        queue<node*> mq;
        queue<node*> hq;

        mq.push(root);

        while(!mq.empty())
        {
            node *removed = mq.front();

            cout << removed->data << " ";

            mq.pop();

            if(removed->left != nullptr)
                hq.push(removed->left);
            if(removed->right != nullptr)
                hq.push(removed->right);

            if(mq.empty())
            {
                cout << endl;
                mq.swap(hq);
            }
        }
    }


};

void destruct(node *root)
{
    if(root == nullptr)
    {
        return;
    }
    if(root->left != nullptr)
    {
        destruct(root->left);
        root->left = nullptr;
    }
    if(root->right != nullptr)
    {
        destruct(root->right);
        root->right = nullptr;
    }
    
    delete root;
}

int main(){
    #ifndef ONLINE_JUDGE
        freopen("input.txt","r",stdin);
        freopen("output.txt","w",stdout);
        freopen("error.txt","w",stderr);
    #endif
    /**
     *  Tree diagram
     *      50
     *     /  \
     *    25   75
     *   / \   / \ 
     *  12 37 62  87
     *      /  \
     *     30  70
     */
    vi v = {50,25,12,-1,-1,37,30,-1,-1,-1,75,62,-1,70,-1,-1,87,-1,-1};
    
    BT b(v);
//  b.levelOrderLineWise();
            
    destruct(b.root);
            
    if(b.root != nullptr)
    {
        cout << "root is still there" << endl;
    }else{
        cout << "tree destroyed" <<endl;
    }
    
    
    if(b.root->left != nullptr)
    {
        cout << "It is still there";
    }else{
        cout << "completed";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**INFO ABOUT CODE**

This is the code for creating a binary tree,we have a class called `node` which has a `data` and two pointers to its children `left` & `right`.

The constructor takes a vector `v` and creates the tree using the elements of the vector in the preorder fashion.

Then I have a function `levelOrderLineWise` in the class `BT` which prints the tree in line wise fashion.

The function `destruct` is supposed to destroy the tree. The algorithm takes the root of the tree and destroys the `left` child(if it is not `nullptr`) and then makes `left` child of `root` equal to nullptr. Similarly, I have destroyed the `right` child(If it is present) and then made the `right` child of `root` equal to `nullptr`.

I get that this algorithm would not make the `root` of the tree `nullptr` but i expect it to make `root->left` and `root->right` equal to `nullptr`. But to my disappointment i am not getting the desired output.

Is there any flaw in my logic? If no,then why is it that i am getting the message `It is still there`?

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

Basically, I get what @john is saying, i should not have included the conditions `if(root->left != nullptr)` and `if(root->right != nullptr)`.

so this would translate something like this

```
void destruct(node *root)
{
    if(root == nullptr)
        return;

    destruct(root->left);
    // root->left = nullptr;
    destruct(root->right);
    // root->right = nullptr;
    delete root;
}
```

But I still dont get why is there not a need for the conditions `root->left = nullptr` and `root->right = nullptr`

*`reason why i think so they are necessary`*

From what i know is that whenever you deallocate the memory pointed by a pointer you must also set that pointer to `nullptr`.

Comment: `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` -- Use the correct standard headers.  This is not a standard header. -- `#define vi vector<int>` -- don't use crazy macros like this.  Use `using VectorInt = std::vector<int>;`

Comment: After destroying the tree, your root pointer is dangling and so any attempt to access data it used to point at is meaningless. In fact, it is undefined behavior.

Comment: *Is there any flaw in my logic?* -- There must be -- why would the program behave the way it does?  -- *I get that this algorithm* -- A program is not an algorithm.  An algorithm should never be incorrect -- implementing the algorithm by writing the program *may* be incorrect.  That's why you should debug the code to see where your code doesn't follow the algorithm.

Comment: General notes: by having a function `destruct` that is responsible for destroying the tree, you're breaking the concept of encapsulation. The class should be entirely capable of managing its own data. Nobody else should be able to access or manipulate its internal structure via pointers or otherwise. Implement a constructor and a destructor on the class. Implement methods for accessing and modifying the tree. Implement copy construction and assignment operator, or explicitly delete them. Make internals private. Don't use the `vi` macro. Just use `std::vector<int>`. Get comfortable typing it.

Comment: @paddy so that means after i have deleted the `tree` i also need to set `b.root` as `nullptr`.

Comment: Yes, otherwise you have an invalid tree.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie will surely try to not use these macros and headers from the next time,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be a lot simpler

```
void destruct(node *root)
{
    if(root == nullptr)
        return;
    destruct(root->left);
    destruct(root->right);
    delete root;
}
```

does exactly the same as your code.

`root->left` and `root->right` cannot have any defined value after `delete root;` so I'm not sure what you are expecting.

Comment: _`root->left` and `root->right` cannot have any defined value after delete root_. What does that mean??

Comment: But I still dont get why is there not a need for the conditions `root->left = nullptr` and `root->right = nullptr`

_`reason why i think so they are necessary`_

From what i know is that whenever you deallocate the memory pointed by a pointer you must also set that pointer to `nullptr`.

Comment: @Abhishekjha When you delete memory the contents of that memory become inaccessible, any attempt to examine that memory causes undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Abhishekjha *From what I know is that whenever you deallocate the memory pointed by a pointer you must also set that pointer to nullptr* **That is completely and utterly incorrect**.

Comment: so why do people after deallocating a memory set that pointer to nullptr.

Comment: @Abhishekjha Because they want the pointer to have a defined value. But memory being pointed to has no defined value after a delete.

Comment: so even if i include the conditions `root->left = nullptr` and `root->right = nullptr` that makes complete sense. Am i right

Comment: The word that is wrong in your statement is **must**, you may set a pointer to null after a delete. But when that pointer itself is contained in memory that is about to be deleted, then there is no point.

Comment: @Abhishekjha I don't understand your last question.

Comment: so basically when i did `destruct(root->left)` and `destruct(root->right)` there was actually no sense in doing `root->left = nullptr` and `root->right = nullptr` because at the very next step i am deleting `root` as well. Is this what you are telling?

Comment: @Abhishekjha Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Finally i got it ^^".

Comment: Makes me wonder if any compiler would optimize that `root->left/right = nullptr` away: https://godbolt.org/z/Knbf41xaE I've implemented a number of variations on `destruct`. "gcc -O2" goes completely bananas. Looks like it inlines the recursion a few times. "gcc -Os" is much saner and notice `destruct5: jmp destruct4` there. It recognizes that they are the same. All the compilers seem to remove `root->right = nullptr;` but not `root->left = nullptr` because `root->right` could point to `root`, directly or indirectly, and then it has an effect. When I reorder in `destruct4` it gets removed.

Answer (score 2):

After you `delete` the pointer, you're not allowed to access the memory that it points to (it's undefined behavior and will likely lead to crashes). So, accessing `b.root->left` is illegal. In practice, when you deleted the root, it likely changed the memory there as some of its bookkeeping for tracking memory allocations, which is probably why the data that's where `b.root->left` *used* to be is nonzero. It's good practice to set the pointer to `nullptr` whenever you `delete` it so you can't make this kind of mistake as easily.

Comment: So you mean that even trying to access `b.root` is illegal after i have called the destruct function.

Comment: Well, you can still check if b.root is not nullptr if you want, but you can't access what it points to with * or ->.

Comment: after deallocating  the memory pointed by `b.root`, it might happen that `b.root` be pointing to some random location in memory. So `b.root` being `nullptr` would be a pure coincidence. Is this correct?

Comment: `b.root` won't be `nullptr` unless you set it to `nullptr`. In practice the pointer is just a memory address number and the number doesn't change on its own. `delete` only invalidates what's at that memory address. (The specifics of how the pointer is stored may be compiler or platform dependent, but I'm pretty sure it still retains whether or not you've set it to `nullptr`)

Comment: So you mean that `b.root` is still pointing to the same memory location, it's just that that memory has been marked for reuse by using the delete keyword. Any attempt to examine that memory location(which has been marked for reuse by delete keyword) would result in undefined behaviour. So,In short, whenever i deallocate a memory pointed by a pointer, better just set it to `nullptr`. Am i correct?

Comment: Exactly! Also, stack overflow is requiring this comment to be more characters than the word "exactly" has.

Answer (score 1):

Personally if you go for setting pointers to `nullptr` after `delete` I like this construct:

```
void destruct(node *&root) {
    if (root == nullptr) return;
    destruct(root->left);
    destruct(root->right);
    delete root;
    root = nullptr;
}
```

By passing `root` as reference you can actually change the pointer from the caller. So after `destruct(root->left);` the `root->left` will be `nullptr`. More importantly though the `root` of the whole tree will become `nullptr`.

Unfortunately this prevents optimizing the `nullptr` setting away. Compare the generated code for various `destruct` flavours on godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/M9bfM68P8

The overhead of `root = nullptr;` is nothing compared to a `delete` call. It will even be in cache unless the tree is really big. So I wouldn't worry about it.